# Karate - Security & vulnerability scan report

Tags: testing, karate

We are working on implementing Karate automation framework for one of our client and they are asking for security and vulnerability scanning report before onboarding it to their network. Is there anything available for latest 1.4.0 version that we can utilise and share readily. The maven repository does show it is vulnerability free but not sure how accurate and detail it would be as it shows clean for all the previous versions whereas there has been subsequent fixes in latest one.

I have tried looking at maven central repository but not convinced if this should be enough to share with customer.